# How to pass Object/Array as variable to NgFor in a dynamic Select control?

Tags: angular

I am creating a dynamic form using few examples. All good if I have the static option values defined in the template for Select component. But since it is dynamic, i want to render select options from a method.

```
<div*ngFor="let control of FormData.controls">
<mat-select [formControlName]="control.name">
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of Countries">item.name</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</div>
```

now i want to make this dymaic for States, fruits etc

```
*ngFor="let item of 'Countries'"
```

any ways to make it dynamic and driven this from json template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you creating an object and having the arrays in a key value pair like below,

```
myNewObj = {}
**somewhere in my code**
this.myNewObj = {
  array1:['data1', 'data2'],
  array2:['data3', 'data4']
}
```

In HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myNewObj['array1']">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: mostly these values are flowing from an API, so currently what i am doing is getting it by a function call *ngFor="let item of GetObject(control.name) | async". Is this good?

Comment: I was about to suggest using a custom pipe, since you're using async pipe already it's good to go

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add value inside the mat-option.

```
<div*ngFor="let control of FormData.controls">
    <mat-select [formControlName]="control.name">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of Countries" [value]="item.name">item.name</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </div>
```

Comment: i am not looking to bind the values.. i want to make this country binding dynamic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).